# tkinter: get index of a clicked widget inside a list of widget objects

Tags: python, tkinter

The following code creates a list of tk entry widgets and then displays them in a tk root window. Each entry includes a binding to a left mouse click that calls an event handler. The event handler identifies which entry widget was clicked using event.widget.

```
def event_handler(event):
    clicked_entry = event.widget
    print(clicked_entry)
    
# Create list of tk entry widgets
    entry_list = []
    for index in range(0,10):
        entry = tk.Entry(root)
        entry.bind('<Button-1>',event_handler)
        entry_list.append(entry)
    
# Display entry widgets on screen
    for index in range(0,10):
        entry_list[index].pack(side=tk.TOP)
```

The output of the event handler, for index items 0, 1 and 2, is as follows:

```
.!entry    # index 0
.!entry2   # index 1
.!entry3   # index 2
```

So I have written a revised event handler that manipulates the event.widget information to produce a correct index value:

```
def event_handler(event):
    clicked_entry = event.widget
    entrystr = str(clicked_entry)
    stripped_entrystr = entrystr.replace(".!entry","")
    if stripped_entrystr == "":
        clicked_index = 0
    else:
        clicked_index = int(stripped_entrystr)-1
    print(clicked_index)
```

This works perfectly, and produces an integer representing the correct index of the clicked entry widget in the list. However, it seems like a laborious way to get at this information. I wonder if there is a simple method to accomplish the same thing - with emphasis on 'simple' - I have seen solutions to similar questions on Stack Overflow that were very complex (and beyond my understanding). If there is no simpler solution, then I'd appreciate knowing if there is anything wrong with my approach that I should be aware of. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def event_handler(event):
    clicked_entry = event.widget
    print(entry_list.index(clicked_entry))
```

Inside the  `event_handler`  function, we get the clicked widget `clicked_entry` using `event.widget` and then get its index inside the  widgets  list using  `entry_list.index(clicked_entry)`. Finally, we print the index to the console.